# Creation of sequence from unstructured table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, group-by

How to split the below unstructured table into 500 records for each batch based on CREATED_DT < SYSDATE -2 considering there are more 90,000 records? I cannot just take the CREATED_DT as the date and the value will change

```
NUMBERID | MODEL| NAME | VALUE | CREATED_DT | LOADED_DT
1000     | BOE  | AGT  | 300   | 02-AUG-2016| 02-AUG-2016
1001     | AIR  | ACT  | 400   | 01-AUG-2016| 01-AUG-2016
1000     | EMB  | ADT  | 500   | 02-AUG-2016| 01-AUG-2016
1004     | REL  | GTR  | 140   | 01-AUG-2016| 01-AUG-2016
1001     | SIM  | HJT  | 140   | 01-JUL-2016| 28-JUL-2016
1002     | SIM  | ACT  | 540   | 04-JUL-2016| 04-JUL-2016
```

I can't use the difference of `MAX(NUMBER_ID)` `MIN(NUMBER_ID)` AND `CREATED_DT` as there is high risk of some data being lost. Can I use Oracle `ROWID` column (system column) column to split the records without missing any records?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The analytic function [ROW_NUMBER](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions170.htm#SQLRF06100) can help uniquely order and chunk the rows.

**Sample Schema**

```
drop table test1;

create table test1(numberid number, created_dt date);

insert into test1
select level, sysdate - level * interval '1' second
from dual connect by level <= 100000;
```

**Sample Query and Results**

```
select
    numberid,
    created_dt,
    ceil(row_number() over (order by created_dt desc) / 500) batch_id
from test1
order by created_dt desc;


NUMBERID   CREATED_DT               BATCH_ID
--------   ----------               --------
1          2016-08-02 11:42:48 PM   1
2          2016-08-02 11:42:47 PM   1
3          2016-08-02 11:42:46 PM   1
...
499        2016-08-02 11:34:30 PM   1
500        2016-08-02 11:34:29 PM   1
501        2016-08-02 11:34:28 PM   2
...
```

Comment: @jonheller1 Could you please let me know why are doing "- 1" in "trunc((row_number() over (order by created_dt desc) - 1) / 500) + 1 batch_id" ?

Comment: @Cool_Oracle It was to deal with off-by-one errors.  But it's a bit simpler with CEIL so I changed my answer a bit.